# I'm sick of manually copying my project folder to my DropBox folder. Please SO Jedi's, teach me the ways of the GIT?

Tags: git, c#, wpf

I'm working on a personal project. Not very big and I'm the only one working on it.

What is the basic way to have GIT save my working project to backup? How does GIT check if it's a working version, or I have to manually right click the folder and "commit" it similar to Tortoise SVN?

I'm not interested in the more advanced features because frankly, I won't use them quite yet. I just need to know how to install it on my Windows 7 Machine, and tell it: "Hey bro, see this project? Keep tabs on it, ok?"

Thanks SO. Hopefully you can guys can teach me great things, once again. :D

Comment: "...Windows 7 Machine, and tell it: "Hey bro, see this project? Keep tabs on it, ok?"  -- *that* is not programming-related

Comment: I was using layman terms so it would better describe what I need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you install [Git Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gitextensions/), which includes everything you need, an easy-to-use GUI, plus a Visual Studio plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the basic way to have GIT save my working project to backup?

That would be push it the the shared folder managed by DropBox.
See this [blog entry](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/06/03/version-control-makes-you-a-better-programmer/) as a practical example

> From the project directory of the project you want to share, type:

```
bash$ git clone --bare . ~/Dropbox/Shared/MySharedProject.git
```

> Note: Keep in mind that I’m assuming you already have this project under Git version control.
>   The `–bare` keyword we used in the clone command means that we simply want to create a directory that contains the contents of the .git directory in your project directory and not the actual workspace.
>   The `.git` directory contains all of your code and changes to everything you need is there–it’s just not the actual workspace where xcode works from.
>
> Create a remote (alias) for the newly cloned project by typing:

```
 bash$ git remote add sharedproject ~/Dropbox/Shared/MySharedProject.git
```

> Now you can push any code changes from your working directory to the cloned directory, which, since it is in your Dropbox will automatically be uploaded to the drop box and downloaded by any other computers you have that can access Dropbox.
>   First you need to commit any changes in your working directory with the following command.

```
bash$ git commit -a -m "Commit message"
```

> Then you need to push the changes to the remote with the following.

```
bash$ git push sharedproject master
```

> This pushes your changes to the cloned repository which is in your Dropbox directory. As soon as you do this, you should see the Dropbox icon in your menu bar change to the ’synchronizing’ icon. If your change is small, it will only change for a split second so you’ll have to watch it closely to see that happen.
>   Once your files are committed and have been pushed to your cloned repository, you can now pull the project from another computer.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960799/using-gitdropbox-together-effectively